# R shiny: can I use one variable located in one output in another?

Tags: r, server, shiny

everyone
I am totally new for R shiny. Here is my question:

The following is two parts of coding in server.

```
 output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
    datatable <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header,     sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
    datatable
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))


    output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(datatable(),20)
    aaa <- "afefagfaegar"
    list(summary(data(),20),aaa) 
    })
```

datatable is a data.frame which I want to summarize in output$summary. However, I can not use datatable in output$summary. I also try to define a data.frame at the very first beginning like a <- data.frame. Then I do like a<-datatable. Still not working.
Could you please help me out here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a variable in more than one output, we just have to tweak your code a little bit. The first thing to know is that, just like in R, variables created inside of a function are in a different scope than those created outside of a function. So, in your instance, you created `datatable` inside of `output$contents`, which is why it's currently not useable. So let's create `datatable` outside of that function and then pass it to our functions.

```
datatable <- reactive({
  if (is.null(input$file1)) return(NULL)
  inFile <- input$file1
  dat <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
  return(dat)
})

output$summary <- renderPrint({
  if (is.null(datatable())) return(NULL)
  summary(datatable(),20)
  aaa <- "afefagfaegar"
  list(summary(data(),20),aaa) 
})

output$contents <- renderDataTable({
  if (is.null(datatable)) return(NULL)
  dat <- datatable(datatable())
  dat
}, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
```

By defining `datatable` outside of the other functions, we can now pass it to both functions. We just have to make sure we check that `datatable` isn't NULL before we try to use it.

Comment: Excellent! Please feel free to accept the response if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use `eventReactive`

for example

```
datatab=eventReactive(input$file1,{
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
    datatable <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header,     sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
return(datatable)
})


output$contents <- renderDataTable({
   datatab()
    }, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))


    output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(datatab(),20)
    aaa <- "afefagfaegar"
    list(summary(datatab(),20),aaa) 
    })
```

Comment: You code will produce errors in the app as both `output$contents` and `output$summary` are going to try to use `datatable` before it's been defined. Also, your recent edit now creates `datata`, but then tries to use `datatab` in the other two functions, which will cause errors as well.